# How to get the current object reference in a class method?

Tags: javascript

Usually I develop on Java, and now I am studying JavaScript/HTML5 Canvas things. And I get a strange situation from Java developer's point of view.

There's a html5 canvas object on the html page, and I want to track the mouse click events on this canvas.

I declared class `GameBoard` and initialized its properties:

```
function GameBoard() {
  // defining a property for GameBoard class instance
  this.myProperty = 'some text here';

  // getting canvas element
  this.boardCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  // setting the mouse click event listener
  this.boardCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleMouseClick, false);
}
```

and there's a class method to handle mouse click events:

```
GameBoard.prototype.handleMouseClick = function(event) {

     alert(this.myProperty);

}
```

`handleMouseClick()` will display `undefined` because `this` in `handleMouseClick()` method refers to the HTML5 Canvas instance (boardCanvas).

My question: how can I refer the current `GameBoard` class instance inside of `handleMouseClick` method to get `myProperty` field value defined in the class constructor?

What I am doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the common conventions is to use an alias to `this`, usually with a variable named `self`:

```
function GameBoard() {
    // defining alias
    var self = this;

    this.myProperty = 'some text here';
    this.boardCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    this.handleMouseClick = function()
    {
        // using alias
        alert(self.myProperty);
    };

    this.boardCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleMouseClick, false);
}
```

However, since you're defining the method on the `prototype` here, you can either use `bind` (as proposed by @Alexander) or try this:

```
var self = this;

this.boardCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e)
{
    // calling the function with 'self/this' context
    self.handleMouseClick(e);
}, false);
```

(Thanks to @Alexander for his contributions)

Comment: in example with call, I think should be like this self.handleMouseClick.call(self, e); - http://jsbin.com/vutugi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I think, in our case, use "call" does not make sense, because if you call self.handleMouseClick(e) "this" will be reference to GameBoard

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in order to set `this` for function

```
  this.boardCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleMouseClick.bind(this), false);
```

**Example:** [http://jsbin.com/vutugi/1/](http://jsbin.com/vutugi/1/edit?js,output)